# Can $g\cdot A < A$ for some group action?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Can $g\cdot A$ be a strict subset of $A$ for some group action '$\cdot$' from $G\times G$ to $G$. For some subset $A$ of $G$, for some element $g$ other than identity in $G$.

Where $g\cdot A = \{ g\cdot a \mid a \in A \}$.

Comment: No because $|gA|=|A|$.

Comment: Yes, you can easily write down an example with $G$ infinite cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb Q^*$ be the multiplicative group of nonzero rational numbers and let $A=\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Then if we take $g=2$ we have that $g.A$ is a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't get why can rationals act on Z because for example 1/2 times 3 is not an integer , so the action is not well defined. But for an action g.a is in A for all a in A. So when g = 1/2 the action is not well defined.

Comment: @BhaskarPandey I mean $\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}$. But the group is not acting on $A$, it is acting on itself. The wording on the question suggested that the group was acting on itself and $A$ was some subset of the group.

Comment: @BhaskarPandey If you mean for $A$ to be the entire set the group is acting on and not a proper subset, the answer is no. But I didn't get that from the wording of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I'm interpreting your question:
Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be a set and $\cdot$ be a group action $G\times A \to A$.
Let $g \in G$. Is it possible that $gA$ is a proper subset of $A$?

---

No, this cannot happen. Let $G$ be any group acting on some set $A$.
Let $g \in G$. It is clear that $gA \subset A$.
To show the other inclusion, let $a \in A$ be arbitrary.
Note that $a = g\cdot\underbrace{(g^{-1}\cdot a)}_{\in A} \in gA$.

This shows the other inclusion as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and apologizes for vague definition of action.